# How close can my brown dwarf orbit the sun and still realistically be undetected?

Tags: planets, orbital-mechanics, solar-system

I have an idea to put another life-bearing planet in the solar system. You could have **a brown dwarf orbiting perpendicular to the solar ecliptic**. It's a brown dwarf so that it can send infrared radiation to its closest and tidally locked moon, and heat the lit side up beyond the melting point of water, allowing that body to support life even when it is very far from the sun.

The perpendicular orbit (caused by the thing being an extrasolar capture) is so that it's reasonable that this planet has not yet been discovered by the year 2022; we have mainly been looking along the ecliptic, and for the duration of modern human astronomy the planet has not yet intersected it. A perpendicular orbit would also not perturb the orbit of Neptune that much, leading us not to even suspect the existence of the brown dwarf. The James Webb telescope can be the one that finally discovers it.

That gives me a question. Brown dwarves emit radiation, so even if it is not located where you would expect to find planets, it's bound to show up in pictures of other things - unless it is far enough that the radiation would be too faint.

**What is the minimum realistic orbital distance for my brown dwarf to have gone undiscovered for so long?** Is there any way to estimate that? Can it still be well within the Oort Cloud, or would it have to be so far away that it's basically halfway to Alpha Centauri?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1633/

Comment: If you're trying to be extremely realistic, that brown dwarf would have been detected in the late 1600s or early 1700s. In those ages, people were already predicting the time it would take the Halley comet to come back by integrating the gravitational influence of the gas giants over it. If we were to put that brown dwarf, it would have affected the orbit, thus giving a base to predict where to find your brown dwarf. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halley%27s_Comet#1531%E2%80%931759

Comment: @4.12.22.4.18.0. They were using the effects of the gas giants to calculate when Halley's comet would return, because Halley's comet comes (relatively) close to Jupiter and Saturn. If Halley's comet didn't come close to the brown dwarf in the past few hundred years (which is not unlikely), the people back then wouldn't have noticed anything.

Comment: If only we could close as dupes because it's in an xkcd. This would be like #20 for that one : Not after the WISE survey. Planet X is not there, and neither is Nemesis.

Comment: The BD's gravity would significantly disturb not only the Oort Cloud, but everything that passes through it (like comets).  Predicting the orbit of comets would be highly difficult.

Comment: @Mark Not entirely. I ask for the closest possible orbital distance; and I got answers ranging from 1 to 10 lightyears, which are still valid answers. To the linked question the answer is simply No.

Comment: @KeizerHarm At 10 light years it wouldn't realistically be in the solar system. There are 3 stars that are half that distance from our sun.

Comment: @sphennings I realise that.

Comment: Per the text of the accepted answer to linked question, the answer to this question is 19 thousand AU (0.3 ly).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Any such object would not be orbiting the sun and remain undiscovered past the all-sky survey of [WISE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide-field_Infrared_Survey_Explorer), in 2011. There was an earlier full sky infrared survey, [2MASS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2MASS), that discovered other brown dwarfs, in 2001. It is extremely unlike that both **full sky** surveys would fail to detect a brown dwarf in orbit around the sun, while detecting fainter objects at much further distances.

This telescope scanned the entire sky and was sensitive enough to detect an object of Jupiter's mass out to 1 light year, with 2-3 Jupiter's mass objects being detectable out to 10 light years. Keep in mind that in addition to being many times heavier than Jupiter, your brown dwarf is putting out a massive amount of energy in the infrared spectrum, enough to melt water on it's moon. For perspective that's over 200C warmer than Pluto.

A realistic lower bound on the range of an undetectable brown dwarf is around 10 light years away.

Comment: Thank you for the honest answer. I appreciate that you mentioned that earlier survey as well, making the story somewhat probable if it is set in 2001. Though probably better suited for another question, I wonder if the habitable moon around the brown dwarf could instead be undetected until JWST - assuming the moon never passed directly before the brown dwarf while we were looking at it.

Comment: @KeizerHarm That's entirely dependent upon where your brown dwarf is.

Comment: Ideally some distance practically reachable with current rocketry, so not quite light years away.

Comment: @KeizerHarm - note that delta-v is more of a consideration than distance (although they do correlate to some extent). It's easier to visit something in a circular 1.5AU orbit than something in a circular 0.5AU orbit, for instance. (...to a first approximation, ignoring gravity assists and such.)

Comment: Just for some perspective, at 10 light-years distance the orbital period of a small brown dwarf captured by the sun would be about 500 million years, meaning the sun would go around the milky way twice before the brown dwarf circled the sun once.  Orbital velocity would be around 38m/s, so this would be completely unstable.  The smallest perturbation would break the orbit.

Comment: @J... Imagine the energy required to perturb a star, albeit small.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say the distance is 95,000 AU, as proposed in the [Nemesis star hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemesis_(hypothetical_star)).

> Nemesis is a hypothetical red dwarf or brown dwarf, originally
> postulated in 1984 to be orbiting the Sun at a distance of about
> 95,000 AU (1.5 light-years)

At the moment, Nemesis hypothesis looks highly improbable, however, existence of a brown dwarf at that distance had not been ruled out.

[WISE survey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide-field_Infrared_Survey_Explorer) could detect existence of Jupiter mass objects up to 1 light year (63,000 AU), so we can rule out any brown dwarfs closer than that.

Comment: If you read elsewhere on that page it says that WISE is able to detect Brown Dwarfs, with a temp of 150K, out to 10 light years.

Comment: @sphennings "able to" is the key word here. As far as I know, there is no conclusive review yet to rule out the possibility of any unknown brown dwarfs in this range.

Comment: I'd say that looking everywhere multiple times and not finding anything is about as conclusive as you can get. That's what the full sky part of a full sky survey means.

Comment: @sphennings I'd say let's call my answer "optimistic" and your answer "realistic" :)

Comment: WISE rules out brown dwarfs (considerably larger than Jupiter) out to around 10 light-years/630,000 AU.

Answer (score 3):

**Oort cloud's symmetry.. brown dwarf must have a (far) wider orbit**

I'd like to add another reason this brown dwarf must be many light years away. Any such object *within* [the spherical Oort cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oort_cloud) would have been detected. The Oort cloud is stretching from 0.03 to 3.2 light years. Within ca 1-2 light years, it would have been found, like the other answers point out.. Beyond that range, you'll run into a problem: the Oort cloud can be observed, its *shape* can be measured,

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/312542625_On_the_present_shape_of_the_Oort_cloud_and_the_flux_of_new_comets

it is near spherical (3d).. and therefore the distance must be *much larger*.. The orbit cannot cross the Oort cloud, without astronomers detecting deviations in the Oort cloud density.  The Oort cloud is perfectly spherical, which indicates no heavy objects anywhere near, except the sun. To keep your brown dwarf away from the Oort cloud, you'd need an orbit far beyond it. I don't have the means to calculate this exactly, but I estimate your brown dwarf would need to be 10-30 light years away from the sun (see note below), assumed its orbit is circular. Elliptical is ok, but it cannot cross the spherical Oort cloud anywhere. The distance would bring your brown dwarf [in the vicinity of other stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nearest_stars_and_brown_dwarfs), which will make it a "rogue star" rather than an "orbiting star"

**Notes on my distance estimation**

NOTE: as KeizerHarm put in the comments here, Proxima Centauri is nearer. Its distance is only 4.2 light years. Maybe there's a "sweet spot" between 3 and 4 ? I found another source that sais the Oort Cloud extends to about 1 light year, not 3.2

https://www.quora.com/Is-the-Oort-cloud-influenced-by-Alpha-Centauri

Maybe it's not known ? In any case, the orbit should stay away from the Oort Cloud, it excludes an extremely elliptical orbit. That would cross the Oort Cloud !

Comment: But Alpha Centauri is much heavier than a brown dwarf and closer than ten light-years, so how can the Oort Cloud be spherical?

Comment: Ok maybe I overestimate and there's a sweet spot between 3 and 4 ? The outer boundary of the Oort cloud extends to 3.2 light years, not 10 light years. Proxima is only 4.2 light years away. This brown dwarf has an orthogonal orbit.. but indeed you're right, Proxima won't do much, or we haven't seen the deviation. 4.2 is much nearer than 10.

Comment: Found another link about the subject of Oort distance and Proxima, thanks @KeizerHarm for your feedback, I have put an edit.

Comment: And thank you for your answer :)